# Sending data to server with NetworkStream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

My assignment is to make a client that sends a ToString-override method to the server. My teacher sent me a Centralcomputer.exe  which is the serverprogram, this program can recieve single strings and uses my local IP.

I connect without a problem, the problem comes when trying to execute this line `Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, klient.ReceiveBufferSize);` my client freezes and the value of bytesRead is 0.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the serverprogram responds with some "oriental" letters before client freezes.

```
 TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

 public async Task Connecting()
    {
        try
        {

            await client.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 12345);

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullException: {0}" + e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SocketException: {0}" + e);
        }


  public void Sending()
    {
        string sendToServer = "Testing testing";
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendToServer);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

        Int32 bytesRead = stream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);    
        //This is where the client freezes

        MessageBox.Show("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
    }
```

I've never done this type of coding before so I really would appreciate some help just to get started!

Comment: What should be the server response?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, but the output on the server is supposed to be in string format

Comment: I was wondering if the server responds or not right after you send him the message.

Comment: Oh, yeah the respons is about 5 "oriental" letters then the client freezes

Comment: One last question: how do you know the value of the bytesRead variable if the client freezes? It unfreezes after a period of time?

Comment: I just used the step-into function and read from locals

Comment: @AlexanderSwe if Read either hasn't returned, or has returned zero, then whatever is in the buffer is meaningless. The contents of the buffer should *only* be examined based on the return of Read. And rather than describing them as "oriental", why not tell us the bytes? Without knowing what protocol is involved here, even simply trying to interpret them as text may be a mistake, let alone trying to guess what encoding is in use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you ask a question, please let it stay up. You can apply minor edits as desired. [Deleting a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507265/sending-strings-through-a-tcpclient-not-working) and asking again and [deleting that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509328/how-to-send-information-through-tcpclient-to-localhost) and asking again is often interpreted as rude behavior. It's better to just let your post stay up and wait for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two scenarios when you will receive zero here:

- a zero-length read with a zero-length buffer can be used to detect when data *becomes* available
- the inbound socket has been closed

Assuming you didn't request a zero-length read, we can therefore assume the second option, and the socket closed. So: why did it close? Most likely, because the server gave up waiting for a message to reply to. Which suggests that it doesn't think you sent a complete message.

That in turn means one of:

- whatever you sent was not complete by the protocol's definition as expected by the server
- the data is still buffered and didn't send

To rule out the second, make sure you call `Flush()` after the `Write`. If that still doesn't fix it: check the protocol very carefully to see what you were *meant* to send. Maybe you missed a trailing linefeed or similar.

As a side note: any time you're doing a single `Read` on a socket, you've probably made a mistake. TCP isn't message oriented - it is just a stream. This means you always need a read-loop that handles whatever framing protocol is in use.

Comment: The Flush() didn't fix it. Been trying to work this out for two days now.. Did you read my edit? Maybe that changes something

Comment: @AlexanderSwe comment added re your edit. However, ultimately this sounds like a protocol failure, i.e. you've misunderstood what the server expects you to send. Without trying to be immodest, I am very experienced in socket code, and to answer your question further really needs info on what the server wants. As I've already said above, and as another person replied, the first thing I'd try is seeing whether the server expects a CR, LF, CR+LF, or even a LF+CR (very rare) to denote the end of your request.

Comment: Ok, I'll talk to my teacher and ask him. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexanderSwe note: one other possibility is that the server is expecting you to end the *outbound* socket before it replies - this is rare, but does happen sometimes, in single-message-per-socket protocols; to try *that*, use the `Shutdown` method on the socket to shut down **only** the outbound (send) socket, leaving the inbound (receive) socket open.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your server expects a carriage return or/and a line feed before writing something back to the client.

Try to change the following line

```
string sendToServer = "Testing testing";
```

into

```
string sendToServer = "Testing testing \r\n";
```

Since we do not have access to the server's code, there is pretty hard to give you an exact solution.